# Formalism/name of a graph theory problem

Tags: terminology, graph-theory

I'm wondering if there's a formalism/well-known name for this graph theory problem:

- Given $n$ nodes on a map, find the path(s) for visiting the greatest number of nodes given a total constraint on the distance traveled.
- Also, a variation of this: for weighted nodes, find the path(s) for maximizing the sum of the visited nodes' weights.

Comment: Sounds very similar to the traveling salesman problem.

Comment: yes, but I emphasize the point that  1.) not every node has to be visited 2.) there's a constraint on maximum distance allowed

Comment: For not every node to be visited the constrained maximum distance has to be less than that of the traveling salesman problem solution, for this to be a "constrained distance traveled, traveling salesman problem."